# "ImportError: file_cache is unavailable" when using Python client for Google service account file_cache

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I'm using a service account for G Suite with full domain delegation. I have a script with readonly access to Google Calendar. The script works just fine, but throws an error (on a background thread?) when I "build" the service. Here's the code:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
import urllib
import requests
from apiclient.discovery import build

cal_id = "my_calendar_id@group.calendar.google.com"

scopes                = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
credentials           = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('my_cal_key.json', scopes=scopes)
delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('me@mydomain.com')
http_auth             = delegated_credentials.authorize(Http())

# This is the line that throws the error
cal_service  = build('calendar','v3',http=http_auth)

#Then everything continues to work normally
request = cal_service.events().list(calendarId=cal_id)
response = request.execute()

# etc...
```

The error thrown is:

```
WARNING:googleapiclient.discovery_cache:file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuseraccount/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 36, in autodetect
    from google.appengine.api import memcache
ImportError: No module named 'google'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuseraccount/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 33, in <module>
    from oauth2client.contrib.locked_file import LockedFile
ImportError: No module named 'oauth2client.contrib.locked_file'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuseraccount/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 37, in <module>
    from oauth2client.locked_file import LockedFile
ImportError: No module named 'oauth2client.locked_file'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuseraccount/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 41, in autodetect
    from . import file_cache
  File "/Users/myuseraccount/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 41, in <module>
    'file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0')
ImportError: file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0
```

What's going on here and is this something that I can fix? I've tried reinstalling and/or upgrading the `google` package.

Comment: Please note that this *is not* an error, but a warning. Things are still working just find (without cache).

Answer (score 144, accepted):

I am a bit late to the party here but I had a similar problem today and found the answer [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/issues/299)

Solution to only the error : `file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0`

Solution:

change your `discovery.build()` to have the field `cache_discovery=False`
i.e

```
discovery.build(api, version, http=http, cache_discovery=False)
```

Comment: Note that this disables the cache and might be detrimental to performance. A better workaround was posted here: https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/issues/325#issuecomment-274349841

Comment: @Chronial I've added this to my answer to give a little more visibility. definitely better to keep the cache enabled when possible.

Comment: @Chronial for performance, negotiating the service lookup is costly and subject to rate limiting, so caching the entire service handler ( result of discovery.build(...), after discovery and auth negotiation is the better approach ).  Making discovery caching not a significant optimization point, which is why it was removed.

Comment: @PaulKenjora These are two different things. You cannot cache the output of `discovery.build` – I assume that you mean reusing the returned object. That is of course also a good idea, but you need to be aware that these objects are not multithreading-safe. And discovery caching was not removed, it's just broken in many setups.

Comment: @Chronial that workaround just is a more complex way to do the same thing. The cache never gets reused in a single `build()`, so populating an empty dict is the same as not using caching.

Answer (score 11):

The code head of module "google-api-python-client"  said...

```
install_requires = [
     'httplib2>=0.9.2,<1dev',
     'oauth2client>=1.5.0,<5.0.0dev',    <<=============
     'six>=1.6.1,<2dev',
     'uritemplate>=3.0.0,<4dev',
]
```

So, I have uninstalled oauth2client version 4.0.0

Then, I have downloaded oauth2client 1.5.2 in a tar.gz file from offial python site https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth2client/1.5.2

I have installed this downloaded file so I have 1.5.2 version of oauth2client

```
Package                  Version
------------------------ ---------
certifi                  2016.9.26
discovery                0.0.4
distribute               0.7.3
future                   0.16.0
google-api-python-client 1.5.5
httplib2                 0.9.2
oauth2client             1.5.2
pefile                   2016.3.28
pip                      9.0.1
pyasn1                   0.1.9
pyasn1-modules           0.0.8
PyInstaller              3.2
pypiwin32                219
requests                 2.11.1
rsa                      3.4.2
setuptools               28.8.0
six                      1.10.0
uritemplate              3.0.0
```

After that, ALL is working OK again and there is no warning message.

Comment: Given the requirements specified, that's a bug with the module then, right?

Comment: Ftr: after uninstalling v4.0.0 you can install an older version directly through pip: `$ pip install oauth2client==3.0.0`. Cf [releases](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/releases).

Comment: this comand for those who don't know command to uninstall a package: `pip uninstall oauth2client`

Comment: This helps. Thanks!

Comment: Tomos's answer is a simple code fix which doesn't require severely downgrading a package https://stackoverflow.com/a/44518587/4047679

Answer (score 4):

Tried all the solutions that were listed, but none of them worked. Until I tried the (simple) suggestion from @dtk that was listed somewhere in the comments :

Install an older version of oauth2client by running:

```
pip install oauth2client==3.0.0
```

Now everything works fine for me. Thank you @dtk !

Comment: oauth2client is deprecated since 2018. Now is 2020.

Answer (score 2):

I did not want to downgrade my oauth2client. You can use oauth2client 4.1.2 when you set `cache_discovery=False` for `apiclient.discovery.build`. This simple solution silenced the error:

```
service = discovery.build(api_name, 
                          api_version, 
                          credentials=credentials, 
                          cache_discovery=False)
```

[Source](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/299)

Answer (score 0):

To use the Google API for Python client, you need to install it first as Google API is not built-in within the Python modules. The instruction is found in [Install the Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation).

**Installation**

You can either use a package manager or download and install the Python client library manually:

Managed installation

Use pip or setuptools to manage your installation (you might need to run sudo first):

pip (preferred):

`$ pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

Setuptools: Use the easy_install tool included in the setuptools package:

`$ easy_install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

Comment: Thanks, but I've already done that. Like I said, the script works just fine -- it's only the one line that triggers something to throw an error on a background thread.

Comment: Kindly check if this was the one mentioned in this [No module named locked_file #414](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/414) which seems to be resolved in [Fix incompatibility with oauth2client v2.0.0 #182](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/pull/182).

Comment: To be honest, I can't tell. I installed with pip using the instructions from the GitHub page: `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`, so I have version 1.5.4 of the package. There's a contrib submodule, but I don't see a `locked_file` submodule anywhere in the package directory.

Comment: @Clay: See here: https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py#L41

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw this is a reposting of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62126604/1599229)

Since they are technically warnings (not errors), if you don't have direct access to the call, you can do this wherever you instantiate the service to suppress them:

`import logging`
`logging.getLogger('googleapiclient.discovery_cache').setLevel(logging.ERROR)`

With thanks to [theacodes](https://github.com/theacodes) who gave that answer [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/299) (but with a missing 'n' in 'client' that seems to have led to a lot of downvotes there).

See also the discussion [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python/issues/157)

Answer (score 0):

to add to the selected answer, if the `build` function is called by a dependency, and there is no easy way to update it's code, this code can be used to force `cache_discovery` to be `False`:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery

_build = googleapiclient.discovery.build


def no_cache_build(*args, **kw):
    kw["cache_discovery"] = False
    return _build(*args, **kw)


googleapiclient.discovery.build = no_cache_build
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I use `google-api-python-client` to build a service on Cloud Functions.

```
# for Cloud Functions use
def get_service():
    import googleapiclient.discovery
    return googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1',  cache_discovery=False)
```

And finally it worked.