# Upload file to google drive using service account using python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am using below python script to upload files to Google drive.I am using service account to remove any interactive authentication.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
gdrive = 'gdrive_cred.json'
folder_id = "1Ixxxxxx6xxxxxa3Ir-xxxxxxxx"


save_location = "D:/output"
file_name = "sampledata.csv"

# Define function to upload the csv files to gdrive
def upload_option_strike_data(save_location,file_name):
    try:
        creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(gdrive, scopes=scopes)
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
        file_metadata = {
            'name': file_name,
            'parents': [folder_id]
        }
        media = MediaFileUpload(f"{save_location}/{file_name}", mimetype='text/csv')

        file = service.files().create(
            body=file_metadata,
            media_body=media
        ).execute()

    except Exception as e:
        print(
            f"Failed to upload historical data collected for {index}.Function - save_option_strike_data.Exception: {str(e)}")
```

upload_option_strike_data(save_location,file_name)

This script will upload the file to Grive and always gives e below warning message.

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery_cache\file_cache.py", line 32, in <module>
    from oauth2client.contrib.locked_file import LockedFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.contrib.locked_file'
```

How can I fix this warning.

Comment: Does this help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154672/importerror-file-cache-is-unavailable-when-using-python-client-for-google-ser ?

Comment: @JimChr-R4GN4R - thanks. that helped. Adding cache_discovery=False with build resolved it